# Evaluating the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{h=0}^j \frac{a^h(2a)^{j-h}(3a)^{i-j}}{(i+3)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, taylor-expansion

For a broader problem that I am trying to solve, I have (shamefully) inserted one of the computations into wolfram alpha. However, the resulting expression is far cleaner than I expected it to be, and I am having trouble figuring out how exactly the result came to be. I have the following sum:
$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{h=0}^j \frac{a^h(2a)^{j-h}(3a)^{i-j}}{(i+3)!} = \frac{(e^a -1)^3}{6}$

This essentially describes the sum over all possible

$\frac{a^{k1}a^{k2}a^{k3}}{(k1+k2+k3+3)!}$

for integer k1, k2, k3.

The resulting expression of $(e^a -1)^3/3!$ makes some sense; I've tried to work with the expansion of (e^a-1)^3 but I haven't managed to come up with anything sensible...

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Having had a quick look at it, it looks like the only things you need are the formula for the sum of geometric series and the infinite sum definition of exp. Then just simplify each sum starting from the innermost one. It's possible that won't work as I have only quickly looked at it but it is definitely how I would start on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an iterated Cauchy product of the absolutely convergent series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{a^n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{e^a-1}{a}.$$
by itself. We get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \Big(\sum_{p+q+r=n} \frac{a^p}{(p+1)!}\frac{a^q}{(q+1)!}\frac{a^r}{(r+1)!} \Big) = \Big(\frac{e^a-1}{a}\Big)^3.$$

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to see how that can be adapted to the problem I'm looking at but that definitely helps a lot!